# Screensaver causes desktops to swap between monitors on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup on windows 10. Whenever the screensaver kicks in and I unlock the laptop, I discover all programs that were on my left monitor are now on my right monitor, and vice versa.

Is there a way to quickly undo the change or better yet, prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas?